# Is there a way to "clean up" an OpenMDAO component to be pickled after an optimization has been run?

Tags: openmdao

Let's take the example below, but imagine that Comp is a much larger group than depicted. After the optimization is run, we want to be able to pickle comp and then later unpickle is it to call some of it's functions that rely on get_val calls. This is for use in a web interface when the optimization is being run in a callback and the object need to be passed to other callbacks to explore the results.

```py
import openmdao.api as om


class Comp(om.Group):

    def setup(self):
        desvars: om.IndepVarComp = self.add_subsystem('desvars', om.IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
        desvars.add_output('x')
        self.add_subsystem('comp', om.ExecComp('y=x**2'), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_design_var('x')
        self.add_objective('y')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    prob = om.Problem()
    comp: Comp = prob.model.add_subsystem('comp', Comp())
    prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver(optimizer='SLSQP')
    prob.setup()
    prob.run_driver()

    # Here we want to reduce the size of comp and pickle it

    # Something like the following line might be called in a separate callback after unpickling
    print(comp.get_val('y'))
```

Just pickling it works, but taking comp as a sizable group with many sub components, the size of the final object is huge. After `setup` but before `run_driver`, we usually see sizes of around 5-20mb. After `run_driver`, this can skyrocket to over 500 mb making this generally challenging for passing between callbacks.

Is there any way to "clean up" the comp object to bring it back to the size that it was after the setup call, but retaining the values of variables that were set by the driver?

**Update**:
I ultimately moved towards the prob.load_case approach that Justin and swryan sugguested. I was able to drop the runtime down on the case recording from >1min to <10 secs by taking some of the suggestions below, but the main time drop came from changing the behavior of the sqlite journal_mode as seen in the snip below

```py
recorder = om.SqliteRecorder(filepath, record_viewer_data=False)
prob.add_recorder(recorder)

prob.setup()
prob.final_setup()
with recorder.connection as c:
    c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY')
```

This prevented a .sql-journal file being generated hundreds of times as all the subsystems were looped over and rather kept the journal in memory instead. This can apparently be a little more susceptible to database corruption, but ended up making the use of the CaseRecorder feasible for my particular application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that components don't actually contain their own state --- even though they kind of look like they do. They have some pointers to vector views that actually point back to the global problem level vector. So when you pickle a component, you're actually saving data from the whole problem. In other words, components are not at all designed to work as stand alone objects. They are children of the problem, and need the surrounding problem to function properly. So that increase in size you see is all the memory allocation and and various other setup that the problem does on behalf of the component.

However, If I understand you use case correctly then it seems like you are only trying to recall the data itself and don't need the ability to re-execute the model (e.g. call run_model or run_driver again) in order to plot the data. So trying to recreate the entire model object seems like overkill.

Instead I recommend you use the [CaseRecorder](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/recording/case_recording_options.html) and [CaseReader](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/recording/case_reader.html) objects. These are designed specifically to save and reload the numerical data. The Reader object even provides the same `get_val` interface (at the problem level) that the original problem does.

Perhaps there is a reason that you don't want to the the CaseRecorder though. In that case, the second best option I can provide to you is to pickle the output vector of the Problem object. Then when you need to reload the data later, you can re-instantiate and re-setup a clean Problem object and then push the old output vector values into it. Then you should be able to call `get_val` and `set_val` on the problem or objects. There is certainly a way to do this, because the `[load_case][3]` method does essentially exact this thing. However `load_case` takes a case object, which comes from a CaseReader. So again, I really recommend you use the `CaseRecorder` and `CaseReader` objects.

Since you have a web-application, you could potentially even write your own CaseRecorder/Reader objects to work on your web database instead of a local SQLite file.

Another strong advantage of the CaseRecorder method is that it gives the model builder [fine-grained control over what data gets saved and when](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/features.html#recording-data). Including saving different granularity of data at different times. For example, you can configure the driver to save the DV variables, constraints, and objective only. So your time-history of optimization won't be massive amounts of data. But you may also want one final case saved that does have EVERY variable in the model --- which would be too much data to save for every iteration--- [so you can configure the Problem recording options to be more broad.](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/recording/problem_recording.html) Then you can manually trigger one case to be saved with all the variables using the `prob.record('final')` call.

Comment: Hey Justin thanks for the suggestions - CaseReaders were the first place I looked however I steered away from them for two reasons - 1 the case readers want to save all the problem meta data as well as the values and for the problems at hand this tends to take about a minute (I think this stems from looping over and saving some very large options dictionaries that are passed through all components). Secondly, the case reader needs to be instantiated before the run_driver call, meaning that it adds about a minute to all runs - not just the ones that should be saved.

Comment: I'll take a look at the output vector option and see if I can get something working from that

Comment: That is a lot of time to spend doing data recording. There is an init arg on the case recorder that lets you turn of *some* (but im not sure how much) of that extra work: https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/recorders/case_recorder.py#L50

You can tell it not to record the N2 and the associated meta-data. But perhaps there is a need for a fast/lightweight case recorder.

Comment: Turning off this option bring down the run time about 10 seconds or so, but the option that would really bringdown the runtime is CaseRecorder._record_metadata (Changing it manually brings the time down to ~5 seconds). Currently, the option to set this to False is depreciated and when I manually do so, an error arises when loading in to the CaseReader

Answer (score 1):

If the issue here is the recording of the options metadata on all of your Components, then one possibility is just setting:

```
comp.recording_options['options_excludes'] = ['*']
```

on the problematic Systems.

https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/recording/system_recording.html?highlight=options_exclude

If there are only specific options that are causing the issue than you can be more selective about which ones to exclude, or use the `recordable=False` option when declaring those options as described [here](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/POEMs/blob/master/POEM_010.md).

```
import openmdao.api as om

class Comp(om.Group):

    def setup(self):
        desvars: om.IndepVarComp = self.add_subsystem('desvars', om.IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
        desvars.add_output('x')
        self.add_subsystem('comp', om.ExecComp('y=x**2'), promotes=['*'])
        self.add_design_var('x')
        self.add_objective('y')

        self.recording_options['options_excludes'] = ['*']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prob = om.Problem()
    comp: Comp = prob.model.add_subsystem('comp', Comp())
    prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver(optimizer='SLSQP')

    recorder = om.SqliteRecorder("recording.sql", record_viewer_data=False)
    prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)

    prob.setup()
    prob.run_driver()

    # Something like the following line might be called in a separate callback after unpickling
    reader = om.CaseReader("recording.sql")
    case = reader.get_case(-1)
    print(case.get_val('comp.y'))
```

Comment: While at first I thought it was the the options dictionary that was the problem, it turned out to be the .sql file writes. I made a recursive loop to add ` self.recording_options['options_excludes'] = ['*']` to all subsystems, and it did save a couple of seconds, but the big drop came from a change to the SQL journal_mode as described in the update